# GetX PageView throws error "[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected..." on swipe?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have an app that displays 4 different charts. Initialization works fine, but as soon as I try to swipe between them (after refreshing the initial data, with the initial data swiping works fine), I get an error:

```
[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
```

Here id the code for the PageView

```
import 'package:adminapp/controllers/controllerDashboard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:adminapp/classes/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:liquid_pull_to_refresh/liquid_pull_to_refresh.dart';
import 'package:adminapp/classes/customBarChart.dart';
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final ControllerDashboard dashboardController =
      Get.put(ControllerDashboard());


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    PageController pageControllerStatistics = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
      keepPage: true,
    );

    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffKey,
        backgroundColor: globals.colorMainPageBackground,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 130,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () => scaffKey.currentState?.openDrawer(),
                              child: const Icon(
                                Icons.menu,
                                size: 30,
                                color: globals.colorBlueDarkLightAccent,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    RichText(
                                        text: TextSpan(
                                            text: 'Hello, ',
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: globals.colorBlueDarkText,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                              fontSize: 24,
                                            ),
                                            children: [
                                          TextSpan(
                                            text:
                                                GetStorage().read('firstname'),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: globals.colorBlueDarkText,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 24,
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ])),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 280,
                                  height: 30.0,
                                  child: AutoSizeText(
                                    GetStorage().read('communityname'),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: globals.colorBlueDarkText,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        fontSize: 14.0),
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Obx(
                    () => dashboardController.isLoading.value
                        ? const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              child: Text("Loading"),
                            ),
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: LiquidPullToRefresh(
                  color: globals.colorMainPageBackground,
                  backgroundColor: globals.colorMainPageBackgroundDark,
                  springAnimationDurationInMilliseconds: 200,
                  showChildOpacityTransition: false,
                  onRefresh: () => dashboardController.syncDashboard(),
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 215,
                        child: PageView(
                          controller: pageControllerStatistics,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Obx(() => CustomBarChart(
                                chartName: "VISITORS",
                                chartData: dashboardController.chartVisitorData
                                    .toList())),
                            Obx(
                              () => CustomBarChart(
                                  chartName: "VEHICLES",
                                  chartData: dashboardController
                                      .chartVehicleData
                                      .toList()),
                            ),
                            Obx(
                              () => CustomBarChart(
                                  chartName: "MAIL",
                                  chartData: dashboardController.chartMailData
                                      .toList()),
                            ),
                            Obx(
                              () => CustomBarChart(
                                  chartName: "PACKAGES",
                                  chartData: dashboardController
                                      .chartPackageData
                                      .toList()),
                            ),
                          ],
                          onPageChanged: (index) => {
                            dashboardController
                                .updatePosition(double.parse(index.toString()))
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Obx(
                        () => DotsIndicator(
                            dotsCount: dashboardController.totalDots.value,
                            position:
                                dashboardController.currentPosition.value),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Obx(() => dashboardController.statusIcons.value),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

All of the dashboardController.chartXXXXData variables are .obs and inside the dashboardController.

Any idea? I was thinking that PageView might need to be wrapped in Obi as well, but that does not work.

UPDATE: As suggested, changed to GetBuilder but does not work?

```
   GetBuilder(
                          init: dashboardController,
                          builder: (_) => SizedBox(
                            height: 215,
                            child: PageView(
                              controller: pageControllerStatistics,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Obx(() => CustomBarChart(
                                    chartName: "VISITORS",
                                    chartData: dashboardController
                                        .chartVisitorData
                                        .toList())),
                                Obx(
                                  () => CustomBarChart(
                                      chartName: "VEHICLES",
                                      chartData: dashboardController
                                          .chartVehicleData
                                          .toList()),
                                ),
                                Obx(
                                  () => CustomBarChart(
                                      chartName: "MAIL",
                                      chartData: dashboardController
                                          .chartMailData
                                          .toList()),
                                ),
                                Obx(
                                  () => CustomBarChart(
                                      chartName: "PACKAGES",
                                      chartData: dashboardController
                                          .chartPackageData
                                          .toList()),
                                ),
                              ],
                              onPageChanged: (index) => {
                                dashboardController.updatePosition(
                                    double.parse(index.toString()))
                              },
                            )
```

Ad changed the controller code to (added update()):

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Chart data
      var data = json.decode(response.body['d']);
      chartVisitorData = data['GraphVisitorsByHoursForToday'];
      chartVehicleData = data['GraphVehiclesByHoursForToday'];
      chartMailData = data['GraphMailByHoursForToday'];
      chartPackageData = data['GraphPackagesByHoursForToday'];
      // print(userData);

      update();
    }
```

Comment: Had your main.dart file contains GetMaterialApp instead of MaterialApp?

Comment: I think you don't need  to add toList() in observableList. Try to remove it please.

Comment: @Vaidarbhi yes.

Comment: Need to see full code of this file to precisely debug the issue.

Comment: @MoïseRajesearison is I don't use .Tolist() it throws the error at initialization of the first set of Widgets in the PageView.

Comment: @BlazingRSj edited with full code. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put your `LiquidPullToRefresh` in Obx, as you are using `dashboardController` at **onRefresh**.

Suggestion:
You should remove all the other `Obx` and go on from here, like if your expected data is not showing then you should put that widget in `Obx`.

Answer (score 0):

Obx and Getx work only with reactive variable
use Getbuilder instead
and when get data in your controller use update() it should work

Comment: Please check the updated code, it docent work as suggested.

Comment: first change this: GetBuilder
to this : GetBuilder<ControllerDashboard >, second : remove all obx widget

Answer (score 0):

## Method - 1

You can try to wrap the whole `PageView` inside ObX instead of wrapping each items inside it.

Also, if your data type is Rx, then you can ommit the `.toList()` method in the UI.

## Method - 2

You can try using `GetBuilder` instead of Obx. But in that way, you have to manually call the `update` method at the end of the function. And you have to wrap your PageView inside the `GetBuilder`.

Comment: Tried #1 earlier, didn't work. Throws the same error.

Tried #2 now, does not work either. Is the code correct?